# CSS3 transition-duration/delay not working for color property, all others working

Tags: css, colors, transition

Using CSS3 "transition."  Strangely, I can successfully manipulate the **top** and **background-color** *values*, *duration*, and *delay*.  I can also manipulate the **color** *value*.  BUT, I cannot manipulate *duration* or *delay* for **color**, no matter what numbers I put in there.

Code is below.  The result here is that **top** and **background-color** complete their changes over 1s, and **color** changes instantly (instead of over 0.5s with 1s delay).

The HTML:

```
<div class="episode">
    <span class="vidsliderprep"></span>
    <span class="vidslider">
            <strong>TITLE</strong>
    Description.</span>
</div>
```

The CSS:

```
.vidslider {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
        top: 108px;
        left: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 120px;
    background-color: rgba( 51, 51, 51, 0.4);
    font-family: 'Gafata', sans-serif;
        font-size: 15px;
        color: #FFF;
        text-shadow: 1px 1px 0px #000;
    padding: 0 10px;
    transition: top 1s ease, background-color 1s ease, color 0.5s ease 1s;
    z-index: 99;
}

.vidsliderprep:hover + .vidslider {
    top: 30px;
    background-color: rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.8);
}

.vidslider strong {
    display: block;
    font-size: 16px;
        font-weight: bold;
}

.vidsliderprep:hover + .vidslider strong {
    color: #F60;
}
```

Many thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

Since it is the `<strong>` color you wish to change, you need to add the transition to that element instead of the parent. [`transition-property`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-transitions/#transition-property-property) is not inherited so the `<strong>` has no transition and therefore the color change is instant.

So add the following rule:

```
.vidslider strong {
    transition: color 0.5s ease 1s;
}
```

and remove that part from the parent if it is no longer needed.

[**See demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/aHN5u/)